# Trying to parse `request.body` from POST in Django

Tags: python, json, django, python-3.x, backbone.js

For some reason I cannot figure out why Django isn't handling my `request.body` content correctly.

It is being sent in `JSON` format, and looking at the `Network` tab in Dev Tools shows this as the request payload:

```
{creator: "creatorname", content: "postcontent", date: "04/21/2015"}
```

which is exactly how I want it to be sent to my API.

In Django I have a view that accepts this request as a parameter and just for my testing purposes, should print `request.body["content"]` to the console.

Of course, nothing is being printed out, but when I print `request.body` I get this:

```
b'{"creator":"creatorname","content":"postcontent","date":"04/21/2015"}'
```

so I know that I *do* have a body being sent.

I've tried using `json = json.loads(request.body)` to no avail either. Printing `json` after setting that variable also returns nothing.

Answer (score 229, accepted):

In Python 3.0 to Python 3.5.x, `json.loads()` will only accept a unicode string, so you must decode `request.body` (which is a byte string) before passing it to `json.loads()`.

```
body_unicode = request.body.decode('utf-8')
body = json.loads(body_unicode)
content = body['content']
```

In Python 3.6, [`json.loads()` accepts bytes or bytearrays](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads). Therefore you shouldn't need to decode `request.body` (assuming it's encoded in UTF-8, UTF-16 or UTF-32).

Comment: This solved my problem! And accessing the elements works like `body['keyname']`. Thank you very much.

Comment: This was very insightfull after countless nights

Comment: thank you. i had the same problem only for one env and it turns out the problematic env is using py3.5

Comment: It didn't work, I get the same error.

Comment: @DerekPK please ask a new question and include your code and the full error message so that other users see it. I don’t think you’ll get help in the comments here.