# receiving incomplete data when using python requests

Tags: python, json, django, post, request

I'm crawling a website and gathering it's data. I have some crawler machine, where they send data to a central server. Part of code in crawlers which send data to server is as follows :

```
requests.post(url, json=data, timeout=timeout, cookies=cookies, headers=headers)
```

At the central server side which uses django, I have the following code:

```
def save_users_data(request):
    body = json.loads(request.body)
    // do something on data received
```

sometimes  server receives incomplete data from crawlers and so json package cannot load data and raises error. For example server received following data in request.body :

```
b'{"social_network": "some network", "text": "\\u0646\\u06cc\\u0633 \\u0628\\u0627\\u06cc\\u062f \\u0622\\u062a\\u06cc\\u0634 \\u062f\\u0631\\u0633\\u062a \\u06a9\\u0631\\u062f\\u0628\\u0631\\u06af\\u0634\\u062a\\u'
```

and raises following error :

```
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Invalid \uXXXX escape
```

Where is the problem?

**EDIT**

This some lines of nginx error.log file :

```
2018/07/25 12:54:39 [info] 29199#29199: *2520751 client 45.55.4.47 closed keepalive connection
2018/07/25 12:54:39 [info] 29199#29199: *2520753 client 188.166.71.114 closed keepalive connection
2018/07/25 12:55:35 [info] 29199#29199: *2520755 client 45.55.4.47 closed keepalive connection
2018/07/25 12:55:58 [info] 29199#29199: *2520757 client 45.55.4.47 closed keepalive connection
2018/07/25 12:55:59 [info] 29199#29199: *2520759 client 45.55.197.140 closed keepalive connection
2018/07/25 12:56:03 [info] 29199#29199: *2520761 client 188.166.71.114 closed keepalive connection
2018/07/25 12:56:04 [info] 29197#29197: *2520715 epoll_wait() reported that client prematurely closed connection, so upstream connection is closed too while sending request to upstream, client: 167.99.189.246, server: 91.208.165.33, request: "POST /crawler/save/users-data/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/home/social/centralsystem/centralsystem.sock:/crawler/save/users-data/", host: "91.208.165.33"
2018/07/25 12:56:11 [info] 29197#29197: *2520723 epoll_wait() reported that client prematurely closed connection, so upstream connection is closed too while sending request to upstream, client: 159.89.20.103, server: 91.208.165.33, request: "POST /crawler/save/users-data/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/home/social/centralsystem/centralsystem.sock:/crawler/save/users-data/", host: "91.208.165.33"
2018/07/25 12:56:12 [info] 29197#29197: *2520724 epoll_wait() reported that client prematurely closed connection, so upstream connection is closed too while sending request to upstream, client: 209.97.142.45, server: 91.208.165.33, request: "POST /crawler/save/users-data/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/home/social/centralsystem/centralsystem.sock:/crawler/save/users-data/", host: "91.208.165.33"
2018/07/25 12:56:16 [info] 29199#29199: *2520765 client 67.207.92.190 closed keepalive connection
2018/07/25 12:56:17 [info] 29197#29197: *2520729 epoll_wait() reported that client prematurely closed connection, so upstream connection is closed too while sending request to upstream, client: 188.226.178.98, server: 91.208.165.33, request: "POST /crawler/save/users-data/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/home/social/centralsystem/centralsystem.sock:/crawler/save/users-data/", host: "91.208.165.33"
2018/07/25 12:56:22 [info] 29199#29199: *2520770 client 188.166.71.114 closed keepalive connection
2018/07/25 12:56:26 [info] 29199#29199: *2520767 client 159.89.20.103 closed keepalive connection
2018/07/25 12:56:27 [info] 29197#29197: *2520777 client 159.89.20.103 closed keepalive connection
2018/07/25 12:56:28 [info] 29199#29199: *2520773 client 188.226.178.98 closed keepalive connection
2018/07/25 12:56:28 [info] 29197#29197: *2520779 client 45.55.197.140 closed keepalive connection
2018/07/25 12:56:29 [info] 29197#29197: *2520782 client 188.226.178.98 closed keepalive connection
2018/07/25 12:56:30 [info] 29199#29199: *2520768 client 209.97.142.45 closed keepalive connection
2018/07/25 12:56:30 [info] 29197#29197: *2520781 client 67.207.92.190 closed keepalive connection
2018/07/25 12:56:31 [info] 29197#29197: *2520786 client 209.97.142.45 closed keepalive connection
2018/07/25 12:56:36 [info] 29199#29199: *2520775 client 67.207.92.190 closed keepalive connection
```

Comment: did you try `request.json()` to get  json response?

Comment: I have not tried this but I think my http body is not complete. Am I wrong?

Comment: @JerinPeterGeorge `request.json()` parses the data from request.body itself so it won't help. OP can you check if your server is sending the data correctly? like logging what is being sent

Comment: @ArpitSolanki How can I log what is sent finally on the network? I know there is no problem in my data

Comment: @mohammad I am asking that you log what is sent from your server and check what is received from your central server. That way you will know that something happend over the network

Comment: This problem is mostly related to server but not client. Maybe your server closes connection before receives the whole content. Are you using nginx as reverse proxy server?

Comment: @Sraw I'm using ngnix + gunicorn

Comment: I guess there should be something useful in your nginx access log or error log. Have a check? For example, mismatched content-length.

Comment: @Sraw I think you are write and put last lines of nginx error.log . Do you know what is the problem?

Comment: Try to add `proxy_ignore_client_abort on;` to your nginx config.

Comment: @JonhyBeebop but my client should wait for the server response.

Comment: `so upstream connection is closed too` as you can see. This should be the problem. Upstream connection closed before it should. The reason seems to be that your clients really close connections. Maybe your `timeout` is too short?

Comment: @Sraw timeout is 180 second and actually it's not low but the task may take more time. So should I use a bigger timeout?

Comment: Actually, I don't know :) I don't know what task are you doing and I don't know why you need more than 180s to handle just one single request. So it is hard for others to really solve this problem. Maybe a message queue based structure is better. For example, `django` just add tasks into queue, and there is another thread/process to process the tasks. I guess your clients don't need the response returned from server right?

Comment: My task is writing lots of data to database. My database is really large and writing takes a long time. My clients need the response

Answer (score 0):

***Edit***

Can you try running it with `json.dumps` instead of `json.loads` ?

`json.loads` will only accept a unicode string, so decoding might be necessary.

```
body_unicode = request.body.decode('utf-8')
body = json.loads(body_unicode)
content = body['content']
```

Read it here : [Trying to parse `request.body` from POST in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29780060/trying-to-parse-request-body-from-post-in-django)

Comment: I know my json data is incomplete. My question is why?

Comment: how is that going to help? OP already knows that data is incomplete

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments problem was my `requests.post` timeout was low for my server response and clients closed connections before server resoponse.