# Django Webhook receive post request for Mailgun

Tags: django, webhooks, mailgun

I've setup a webhook in Django to receive updates from Mailgun.

The mailgun POST payload is delivered to the webhook in the below format:

```
{
  “signature”:
  {
    "timestamp": "1529006854",
    "token": "a8ce0edb2dd8301dee6c2405235584e45aa91d1e9f979f3de0",
    "signature": "d2271d12299f6592d9d44cd9d250f0704e4674c30d79d07c47a66f95ce71cf55"
  }
  “event-data”:
  {
    "event": "opened",
    "timestamp": 1529006854.329574,
    "id": "DACSsAdVSeGpLid7TN03WA",
    // ...
  }
}
```

If I try and retrieve `event` parameter using the below code, I get an error saying **TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable**

```
@csrf_exempt
@require_POST
def mailgun(request):
    event_data = request.POST.get['event-data']['event']
    return HttpResponse(event_data, status=200)
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

After a lot of troubleshooting, the answer was hidden in the StackOverflow link below. In Python 3.0 to Python 3.5.x, json.loads() will only accept a unicode string, so you must decode request.body (which is a byte string) before passing it to json.loads().

[Trying to parse `request.body` from POST in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29780060/trying-to-parse-request-body-from-post-in-django)

```
body_unicode = request.body.decode('utf-8')
body = json.loads(body_unicode)
content = body['event-data']
recipient = content['recipient']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to update `.get` to call function and add some input checks, ie:

```py
if request.POST.get('event-data'):
    event_data = request.POST.get('event-data')['event']
    return HttpResponse(event_data, status=200)
else:
    return HttpResponse("[unknown event]", status=400)
```

or if you sure `event-data` never be empty or null call directly:

```py
request.POST['event-data']['event']
```

Comment: If I run the first coomand, I get: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Comment: @Rutnet is it possible you receive `event-data` which is empty?

Comment: @Rutnet updated my answer with extended examples (with response with 400 status code if incoming data is not what you expected)

Comment: I think the event data is not being returned properly. This is the structure of the event_data https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/user_manual.html#webhooks

Comment: okey, could you show ( `print(dict(request.POST))` )  what you actually receive from mailgun?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221108/discussion-between-ujlbu4-and-rutnet).