# Why response is always {"detail":"Unsupported media type \"text/plain\" in request."} in swift?

Tags: swift, django, xcode

I have created a sample app in Django which deletes a question from App. And provides a correct output when consumed using POSTMAN.

```
class Questions(APIView):
  def delete(self,request):
        received_id = request.POST["id"]
        print(received_id)
        place = Question.objects.get(pk=received_id)
        place.delete()
        questions = Question.objects.all()
        seriliazer = QuestionSerializer(questions,many = True)
        return Response({'Orgs': seriliazer.data})
```

However, when I am trying to achieve it from iOS app, it's returning {"detail":"Unsupported media type "text/plain" in request."}

```
func deleteQuestion( id: Int){
    guard let url  = URL(string: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/V1/API/questions/") else {
        return
    }
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    let postString = "id=15"
    request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8);
    request.httpMethod = "DELETE"
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        let str = String(decoding: data!, as: UTF8.self)
        print(str)
        if error == nil {
            self.fetcOrganizatinData()
        }
    }.resume()
}
```

Could not really understand where exactly the problem is ?

Comment: Missing Content-Type header?

Comment: request.setValue("charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")   I added this but still it shows  {"detail":"Unsupported media type \"charset=utf-8\" in request."}

Comment: Status Code: 415 , I really dont understand what exactly its expecting at the server end

Comment: If it's working with POSTMAN, could you ask POSTMAN to generate cURL code? Or Swift code? Also, you di a "DELETE", bu in the code I see a "POST"?

Comment: its just trying to capture the ID from body ,should not be a problem, I generated code but its using multipart , I dont think there needs any multipart code to deal with this

Comment: Usually delete is a command to a resource at a particular endpoint.
 Does the following work without the httpBody?  `URL(string: "https://127.0.0.1:8000/V1/API/questions/\(id)")`

Comment: @Dipesh And the curl generated code equivalent?

Comment: curl --location --request DELETE 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/V1/API/questions/' \
--form 'id="16"'

Comment: i understood the problem is in the code   received_id = self.request.GET["id"],, Now I want to know how to parse body on DELETE method @Jake

Comment: Is `print(received_id)` printed at least? Or are you expecting `let postString = "id=15"` => `let postString = "id=\"15\""`?

Comment: the biggest problem is it works with POST MAN, by swift code its not printing

Answer (score 2):

Shortly add `Content-Type` `application/json` in your headers
**Reason**
this happens because the postman has some default headers usually 8.
One of them is
`Content-Type` `text/plain`
and by writing `"Content-Type": "application/json"` we can overwrite that rule.
So whenever you want to pass your data like JSON do that.
to learn more what is by default in postman
I recommend you to read this [official documentation of postman](https://www.postman.com/shipsaw/workspace/default/documentation/12651936-8037e5d7-1dcd-450e-b7f8-60f13420ffaf).
It happens with me I solved this with overwriting default `Content-Type`

Answer (score 0):

If the api is expecting Json, the body you are sending is not Json, it’s encoded plain text. If it should be Json you can change the body string into the Json format like:

```
“{\”id\”:15}”
// you may want to tell it what you’re sending
request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept-Encoding")
```

Another thing it could be is the request is missing the Accept-Encoding header which tells the api what you’re sending up where Content-Type is what the api typically sends down.

I’ve experienced header injection when I’ve sent requests through specific gateways that aren’t always right. I’d the header isn’t present, something along the way could try to help you out and add the header. This has caused me problems on the past. I still don’t know exactly where in our stack it was occurring, but adding the header fixed my problem.

You can add the header like:

```
request.setValue("charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept-Encoding")
```

Comment: i assumed you are taking about   request.setValue("charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept-Encoding") ,which did not yield result

Comment: i understood the problem is in the code   received_id = self.request.GET["id"],, Now I want to know how to parse body on DELETE method @Jake

Comment: Try this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/29781023/9333764 I'm not familiar with DJango, I am familiar with swift

Comment: you would probably ignore the body["content"] part of that answer

Answer (score 0):

DELETE request's body will be ignored, I could guess from the [Is an entity body allowed for an HTTP DELETE request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299628/is-an-entity-body-allowed-for-an-http-delete-request) post. HENCE Better to send the complete URL or in header itself,

so I made the function as below

```
def delete(self,request):
        received_id = request.headers['id']
        place = Question.objects.get(pk=received_id)
        place.delete()
        return HttpResponse("DELETE view is working fine ")
```

and swift

```
 func deleteQuestion( id: Int){
        guard let url  = URL(string: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/V1/API/questions/") else {
            return
        }
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        //let postString = "id=\(id)"
       // request.httpBody =  postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8);
        request.httpMethod = "DELETE"
        request.setValue("charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept-Encoding")
        request.setValue("charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.setValue("\(id)", forHTTPHeaderField: "id")
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            let str = String(decoding: data!, as: UTF8.self)
            print(str)
            if error == nil {
                self.fetcOrganizatinData()
            }
        }.resume()
    }
```